# How to positon an image behind a box-shadow using z-index?

Tags: css

I want to position an image behind the box-shadow of my header, so that the box-shadow appears on top of my image.

I've been using z-index to achieve this, but haven't been able to make it work.

The code I made is available in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/zrm69/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your position value in header and copy-left to

```
position:relative;
```

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Answer (score 2):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/zrm69/3/

Answer (score 2):

Z-index is ineffectual on statically-positioned elements. Change the header to be `position: relative` and all will be fine.